# Unable to set bubble size matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I have the following pandas dataframe named df:

---

```
            quantity    receita   ticket_medio

PERFUMARIA     0.5        50       0.398174
SABONETE       0.2        11       0.128486
CORPO          0.1        17       0.116748
```

---

With the above dataframe, I want to produce a bubble chart where the x-axis is receita, the y-axis is the quantity and the ticket_medio is the bubble size.

I tried the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
df.plot.scatter('receita', 'quantity', ax=ax, s=df['ticket_medio'])
for k, v in df[['receita', 'quantity']].iterrows():
    ax.annotate(k, v)
plt.show()
```

But I get the following error message:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-93c733a91344> in <module>()
      1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
----> 2 category_frequency.plot.scatter('receita', 'quantity', ax=ax, s=category_frequency['ticket_medio'])
      3 for k, v in category_frequency[['receita', 'quantity']].iterrows():
      4     ax.annotate(k, v)
      5 plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, **kwds)
   2793         axes : matplotlib.AxesSubplot or np.array of them
   2794         """
-> 2795         return self(kind='scatter', x=x, y=y, c=c, s=s, **kwds)
   2796 
   2797     def hexbin(self, x, y, C=None, reduce_C_function=None, gridsize=None,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2615                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   2616                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2617                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   2618     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   2619 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   1857                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1858                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 1859                  **kwds)
   1860 
   1861 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1682         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   1683 
-> 1684     plot_obj.generate()
   1685     plot_obj.draw()
   1686     return plot_obj.result

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in generate(self)
    238         self._compute_plot_data()
    239         self._setup_subplots()
--> 240         self._make_plot()
    241         self._add_table()
    242         self._make_legend()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in _make_plot(self)
    832             label = None
    833         scatter = ax.scatter(data[x].values, data[y].values, c=c_values,
--> 834                              label=label, cmap=cmap, **self.kwds)
    835         if cb:
    836             img = ax.collections[0]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1895                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1896                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1897             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1898         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1899         if pre_doc is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4032                 offsets=offsets,
   4033                 transOffset=kwargs.pop('transform', self.transData),
-> 4034                 alpha=alpha
   4035                 )
   4036         collection.set_transform(mtransforms.IdentityTransform())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in __init__(self, paths, sizes, **kwargs)
    902         Collection.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    903         self.set_paths(paths)
--> 904         self.set_sizes(sizes)
    905         self.stale = True
    906 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in set_sizes(self, sizes, dpi)
    875             self._sizes = np.asarray(sizes)
    876             self._transforms = np.zeros((len(self._sizes), 3, 3))
--> 877             scale = np.sqrt(self._sizes) * dpi / 72.0 * self._factor
    878             self._transforms[:, 0, 0] = scale
    879             self._transforms[:, 1, 1] = scale

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks a lot,

Rodrigo.

Comment: The example code you posted works for me. Matplotlib 2.0.2, Pandas 0.20.3. I do see your error contains different code. Are you certain there are no typos in the column names?

Comment: Works for me as well

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but it still does not work for me. I am using Matplotlib 2.0.2 and Pandas 0.20.2.